# Sybase offset for pagination

Tags: pagination, sybase

Is there any simple way to implement pagination in sybase?
In postgres there are limit and offset in mysql there is limit X,Y. What about sybase? There is top clausure to limit results but to achieve full pagination there is also offset needed.
It is not a problem if there are a few pags, I can simply trim results on the client side, but if there are millions of rows I would like to fetch only data that I need.

Comment: Is this about Sybase ASE or Sybase SQL anywhere? SQL Anywhere supports `TOP .. START WITH ..`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from http://www.isug.com/Sybase_FAQ/ASE/section6.2.html#6.2.12:

> Sybase does not have a direct equivalent to Oracle's rownum but its functionality can be emulated in a lot of cases.

You can set a maximum `rowcount`, which will limit the number of rows returned by any particular query:

```
set rowcount 150
```

That limit will apply until it is reset:

```
set rowcount 0
```

You could select into a temporary table, then pull data from that:

```
set rowcount 150

select pseudo_key = identity(3),
       col1,
       col2
  into #tempA
  from masterTable
 where clause...
 order by 2,3

select col1,col2 from #tempA where pseudo_key between 100 and 150
```

You could optimize storage on the temp table by storing only ID columns, which you then join back to the original table for your select.

The FAQ also suggests other solutions, including cursors or Sybperl.

Answer (score 4):

```
// First row = 1000
// Last row = 1009
// Total row = 1009 - 1000 + 1 = 10
// Restriction: exec sp_dboption 'DATABASE_NAME','select into/bulkcopy','true'
select TOP 1009 *, rownum=identity(10) 
into #people
from people 
where upper(surname) like 'B%'
select * from #people where rownum >= 1000
drop table #people
// It shoulde be better SQL-ANSI-2008 (but we have to wait):
// SELECT * FROM people
// where upper(surname) like 'B%'
//    OFFSET 1000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm very late to the party but I've happened to stumble on this problem and found a better answer using TOP and START AT from sybase doc. You need to use ORDER BY for or you will have unpredictable results.

http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbusage_en11/first-order-formatting.html

SELECT TOP 2 START AT 5 *
   FROM Employees
   ORDER BY Surname DESC;

Comment: OP didn't say which version of Sybase they were using, but worth noting that this answer works in SQL Anywhere but not in Sybase ASE.

Answer (score 1):

Sybase SQL Anywhere example, rows per page:10, offset:1000.

```
SELECT top 10 start at 1001  * FROM employee order by employeeid
```

Note: You need to specify the `order by` column.

Answer (score 1):

as of version 16.x Sybase ASE supports LIMIT and OFFSET
Reference: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/e0d4539d39c34f52ae9ef822c2060077/26d84b4ddae94fed89d4e7c88bc8d1e6.html?version=16.0.2.5&locale=en-US#using-limit-and-offset-together

Comment: TBH this is the only mention in the web about this and I'm playing around on a live server and it doesn't seem to be working... 
Also this says something different: https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1600/doc/html/san1393051059932.html

Comment: It looks you are referring to outdated documentation. You need to make sure you have a version of ASE that supports this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Sybase does not provide the ability to set a start and offset limit. The best you can achieve is to use the SET ROWCOUNT to limit the number of records returned. If you have 1,000 records and want to page by 50 entries then something like this will bring back the first page...

```
set rowcount 50
select * from orders
```

For the second page...

```
set rowcount 100
select * from orders
```

...and then you can choose not to display the first 50 from within your Java code. Obviously as you page forward you end up having to return larger and larger data sets. Your question about what to do with 1,000,000 records doesn't seem practical for a user interface that is paginated. No user searches on Google and then pages forward 1,000 times looking for stuff.

What if I have a Natural Key?

If you do have a relatively large data set and you can use a natural key on your data, this will help limit the records returned. For example if you have a list of contacts and have an interface that allows your users to select A to Z to page the people in the directory based on Surname then you can do something like...

```
set rowcount 50
select * from people 
where upper(surname) like 'B%'
```

When there are more than 50 people with a surname starting with 'B' you use the same approach as above to page forward...

```
set rowcount 100
select * from people 
where upper(surname) like 'B%'
```

... and remove the first 50 in Java code.

Following on from this example, maybe you can limit searches by date, or some other piece of data meaningful to your users requriements.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the set ROWCOUNT twice like this:

```
    declare @skipRows int, @getRows int
    SELECT @skipRows=50
    SELECT @getRows=10
    set ROWCOUNT @skipRows
    SELECT caslsource_id into #caslsource_paging FROM caslsources
    set rowcount @getRows
    Select * from caslsources where caslsource_id not in (select caslsource_id from #caslsource_paging)
    DROP TABLE #caslsource_paging
```

This creates a temporary table of rows to skip. You will need to add your WHERE and ORER BY clauses to both the SELECTs to skip the right pages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is ASE or a different product but the following pattern works across several databases I've worked with as long as there is a way to produce a temp table with a row number somehow and you can identify a unique key for each row:

Input parameters:

```
declare @p_first int /* max number of rows to see; may be null (= all results); otherwise must be positive number */
declare @p_skipFirst int /* number of rows to skip before the results; must be nonnegative number */
declare @p_after PKTYPE /* key for the row before you start skipping; may be null */
```

given a table:

```
RowNumber | RowIndex | DataCol1
1         | 1234     | Joe
2         | 1235     | Sue
3         | 2000     | John
4         | 2005     | Frank
5         | 3000     | Tom
6         | 4000     | Alice
```

the parameter set:

```
set @p_first = 5
set @p_skipFirst = 2
set @p_after = 1235
```

would represent rows 5 and 6.

An additional set of parameters can represent paging from the end of the table in reverse:

```
declare @p_last int /* max number of rows to see; may be null (= all results); otherwise must be positive number */
declare @p_skipLast int /* number of rows to skip after the results; must be nonnegative number */
declare @p_before PKTYPE /* key for the row after you start skipping; may be null */
```

Assuming your unsorted table is in `#resultsBeforeSort` with an index column named `RowIndex` you can sort this with the following script:

```
select RowNumber = identity(10), * 
into #results
from #resultsBeforeSort
/*
you might also wish to have a where clause on this query

this sort is dynamically generated based on a sort expression and 
ultimately ended with RowIndex to ensure a deterministic order
*/
order by Column1, Column2 desc, RowIndex

declare @p_total int, @p_min int, @p_max int
select @p_total = count(*) from #results

select @p_min = case when @p_after is null then 1 + @p_skipFirst else @p_total + 1 end
select @p_min = RowNumber + @p_skipFirst from #results where [RowIndex] = @p_after

select @p_max = case when @p_before is null then @p_total - @p_skipLast else 0 end
select @p_max = RowNumber - @p_skipLast from #results where [RowIndex] = @p_before

declare @p_min2 int, @p_max2 int
set @p_min2 = @p_min
set @p_max2 = @p_max

select @p_max2 = case when @p_first is null then @p_max else @p_min + @p_first - 1 end
select @p_min2 = case when @p_last is null then @p_min else @p_max - @p_last end

select @p_min = case when @p_min2 > @p_min then @p_min2 else @p_min end
select @p_max = case when @p_max2 < @p_max then @p_max2 else @p_max end
```

that script sets up the parameters `@p_min`, `@p_max`, and `@p_total` as well as the temp table `#results`

You can then use this to select actual data; select 2 table results, first one being metadata (select this first because the second table might not have any actual rows and your reader implementation might not be capable of dealing with that without backtracking):

```
select [Count] = @p_total, 
    HasPreviousPage = (case when @p_min > 1 then 1 else 0 end),
    HasNextPage = (case when @p_max + 1 < @p_total then 1 else 0 end)
```

followed by the paged window of results that you actually want:

```
select [RowIndex], Col1, Col2, Col3 
from #results where RowNumber between @p_min and @p_max
```

Doing this generic solution permits the ability to expose whatever paging strategy you wish. You can do a streaming solution (facebook, google, stackoverflow, reddit, ...) via `@p_after` and `@p_first` (or `@p_before` and `@p_last`). You can do an offset + take with `@p_first` and `@p_skipFirst`. You can also do a page + size with the same parameters `@p_first = size` and `@p_skipFirst = (page - 1) * size`. Further you can do more esoteric paging strategies (last X pages, between absolute records, offset + anchor, etc) with other combinations of parameters.

---

This said, Sybase (SAP) ASE does now directly support the offset + take strategy via `rows limit @p_first offset @p_skipFirst`. If you only wished to support that strategy you could simplify the above to:

```
declare @p_total int
select @p_total = count(*) from #resultsBeforeSort

select [Count] = @p_total,
       [HasPreviousPage] = (case when @p_skipFirst > 0 then 1 else 0 end),
       [HasNextPage] = (case when @p_total > @p_skipFirst + @p_first then 1 else 0 end)

select [RowIndex], Col1, Col2, Col3
  from #resultsBeforeSort
  order by Column1, Column2 desc, RowIndex
  rows limit @p_first offset @p_skipFirst
```