# Sybase search result with offset

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am working on Sybase. Want to implement pagination for a result. I can get first few records by stating `set rowcount 100` But is there any way to set start point as well. The result is ordered on basis of a text value.

I tried finding at stackoverflow as well as in Sybase documentations, but could not find the way. I tried `Limit`, `rownum()` etc. but they are not supported. Also tried putting it as inner query, but somehow it is not working.

One solution I found which was of creating temp table with identity and get the same. But to the application, I do not have create table permission.

Can someone please help me in this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sybase offset for pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759166/sybase-offset-for-pagination)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `START AT`. Try:

```
SELECT TOP 25 START AT 50 * FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY Id
```

Comment: Didnot worked. START was not discplayed as keyword. Error came : Incorrect syntax near '50'

Comment: Ok, I should've asked this first. Which Sybase database, and what version are you using? SQL Anywhere?

Comment: Hi, we are working on sybase 15. For querying I am using Rapid SQL

Comment: I see. Please check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759166/sybase-offset-for-pagination (I'm marking the question as duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT and OFFSET are supported in ASE 16, see https://help.sap.com/viewer/cbed2190ee2d4486b0bbe0e75bf4b636/16.0.3.7/en-US/c1881eb182ee4b899f54c577d9dc0ecb.html