# How to do Select query range by range on a particular table

Tags: sql, database, sybase, sap-ase

I have one temp_table which consists of more than 80K rows. 
In aqua I am unable to do select * on this table due to space/memory limitation I guess.

```
select * from #tmp
```

Is there any way to do select query range by range?

For eg:- give me first 10000 records and next 10000 and next 10000 till the end.

**Note:-**

```
   1) I am using Aqua Data Studio, where I am restricted to select max 5000 rows in one select query.

   2) I am using Sybase, which somehow doesn't allow  'except' and 'select top @var from table' syntax and ROWNUM() is not avaliable
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You can do it through a procedure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get N rows starting from row M from sorted table in T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758186/how-to-get-n-rows-starting-from-row-m-from-sorted-table-in-t-sql)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sybase offset for pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759166/sybase-offset-for-pagination)

Comment: Check that!! http://dba.fyicenter.com/Interview-Questions/SYBASE/Selecting_rows_N_to_M_without_Oracles_rownum_in_.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use something like with where clause on some id in the table

```
select top n * from table where some_id > current_iteration_starting_point
```

e.g

```
select top 200 * from tablename where some_id >  1
```

and keep increasing the iteration_starting_point say from 1 to 201 in the next iteration and so on.

Comment: that will always give top `n` records, not a range of records between `m` and ` n`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following in SQL Server.  Just update @FirstRow for each new iteration.

```
declare @FirstRow int = 0
declare @Rows int = 10000

select top (@FirstRow+@Rows) * from Table
except
select top (@FirstRow) * from Table

set @FirstRow = @FirstRow + @Rows

select top (@FirstRow+@Rows) * from Table
except
select top (@FirstRow) * from Table
```

Comment: That's a great solution, but syntax is not allowed in Sybase which I am using

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation on how to increase the memory capacity of Aqua Data Studio :

https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation16/page/50/Launcher-Memory-Configuration

Comment: Yeah I know, but I am not allowed to change the config.