# Create a sql query to generate csv files in batches from the data avaliable in sybase database table

Tags: sql, csv, export-to-csv, sap-ase

Currently, I have written a query which creates CSV file from the data available in a database table. Worked with small data but the actual data is in millions. I am new to SQL and need suggestion to create this CSV file in batches depending on size or rows maybe. It has to be specific to the particular filename. That is the CSV file should be same as that of the filename mentioned in a column in the database.

Any suggestion is much appreciated
Database: Sybase ASE
SQL query

Written a query which creates CSV file from the data available in a database table

Expected result: CSV files should be created in batches depending on size/rows/time of the data present in the database table. It should contain the same filename as present in the column of the database table

Comment: _" I have written a query which creates CSV file..."_ Share your query please.

Comment: The query is simply Select statement. Rest of the logic to create a CSV is different.

Comment: Then break your result table into few smaller tables, and output them into csv one by one. If you don't know how to break it - this might come handy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759166/sybase-offset-for-pagination

Comment: If you're using ASE 16 consider the using [select w/ limit/offset](https://help.sap.com/viewer/e0d4539d39c34f52ae9ef822c2060077/16.0.3.7/en-US/26d84b4ddae94fed89d4e7c88bc8d1e6.html); if using ASE pre-16 then you'll need to get creative based on your specific requirements (see Grzegorz's comment/link and/or provide more details on the criteria for determining batch size)